# Deleting rows with the word 'hate' in a column I called 'Bio' in a spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a line to the code below that I use in Phyton so that it will delete all lines with the word 'hate' in column I, which is called 'Bio':

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

INPUT_FILE = 'Sample spreadsheet.xlsx'
OUTPUT_FILE = 'Output.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(INPUT_FILE)

df.dropna(subset=['Location', 'Full name'], inplace=True)

df = df[(df['Followers'] > 200) & (df['Friends'] > 200) & (df['Last tweet'] > '2011-04-12') & (df['Created'] < '2018-12-31')]
with pd.ExcelWriter(OUTPUT_FILE) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add lowercasing before calling contains! This means Hate, hate, HATE would be caught:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2],
               'bio':['i love pandas',
                      'i HATE ms excel']})

# normalize words to lowercase

#df = df[~ df['bio'].str.lower().str.contains('hate')]
df = df[~ df['bio'].str.contains('hate',case=False)]
```

Pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Results:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Are you willing to show me how that looks look when added to the code in my example?

Comment: You will add it to your masks:\newline df = df[(df['Followers'] > 200) & (df['Friends'] > 200) & (df['Last tweet'] > '2011-04-12') & (df['Created'] < '2018-12-31') & (~df['Bio'].str.lower().str.contains('hate')
)]

Comment: i believe `str.contains()`  would have a `case=` parameter. `str.contains('hate',case=False)` where you wouldnt have to add the `lower()` :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove strings that contains the word "hate":

```
df = df[~df["Bio"].str.contains("hate")]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line

```
df = df[df['Bio'] != 'hate']
```

if the column can contains multiple values you can use

```
df = df[~df["Bio"].str.lower().contains("hate")]
```

Comment: This will only work if there are a single word in a column:)

Comment: i didn't noticed that it contains not equel, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Totally true. The issue is not your answer but the question:)